# Scaling Background Image for Clarity

Tags: fabricjs

I am using the latest version (1.7.22) of the fabricjs library and am trying to get my toggle-able images to be clearer by loading larger images and then scaling them each to fit the canvas. I've tried scaling the image but without luck. I basically want the frame images to fit the canvas. As you can see, the images are twice the size they should be. What am I doing incorrectly?

**My Code**

```js
var canvas = [],
  image;
canvas.push(new fabric.Canvas('c0'));
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  canvas.push(new fabric.StaticCanvas('sc' + i));
}

function dropText() {
  var text = new fabric.IText('Type here...', {
    fontSize: 27,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
  });
  canvas[0].add(text);
}

canvas[0].on('object:added', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:modified', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:scaling', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:moving', onModified);

function onModified(option) {
  var ob = option.target;
  var index = canvas[0].getObjects().indexOf(ob);
  ob.clone(function(obj) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
      canvas[i].insertAt(obj, index, true);
    }
  });
};

$('#update').click(function() {
  updateCanvas();
});

function updateCanvas() {
  var json = JSON.stringify(canvas[0]);
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    canvas[i].loadFromJSON(json);
  }
}
// Toggling Images
function replaceImage(imgUrl) {
  if (!isImageLoaded) return; //return if initial image not loaded
  image.setSrc(imgUrl, function() {
    canvas[0].renderAll();
    updateCanvas();
  });
}

// Default (Blank)
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/SamdNdX.png', function(img) {
  isImageLoaded = true;
  image = img.set({
    selectable: false,
    evented: false,
    scale: 0.5,
  });
  canvas[0].add(image);
  canvas[0].sendToBack(image);
  updateCanvas();
});

$('#save').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#imagesave'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
      a.download = 'myfile.jpg';
      a.click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}

td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#imagesave {
  background-color: white;
  height: 637.5px;
  width: 825px;
  padding-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>

<button onclick="dropText();" class="dropdown-item">Add Text</button><button id="save">Save</button>
<button onclick="replaceImage('https://i.imgur.com/SamdNdX.png')">Blank</button>
<button onclick="replaceImage('https://i.imgur.com/RuZ5HTH.png')">Image A Pic</button>
<button onclick="replaceImage('https://i.imgur.com/u3Knj4R.png')">Image B Pic</button>

<div id="imagesave">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="c0" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc1" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc2" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc3" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc4" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc5" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc6" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc7" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

My background's also not seeming to stick when I save, but I suppose that's a question for later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up finding out what I did wrong. The scaling I tried before posting was fine, I was just writing it after the semicolon. The solution:

```js
var canvas = [],
  image;
canvas.push(new fabric.Canvas('c0'));
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  canvas.push(new fabric.StaticCanvas('sc' + i));
}

function dropText() {
  var text = new fabric.IText('Type here...', {
    fontSize: 27,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
  });
  canvas[0].add(text);
}

canvas[0].on('object:added', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:modified', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:scaling', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:moving', onModified);

function onModified(option) {
  var ob = option.target;
  var index = canvas[0].getObjects().indexOf(ob);
  ob.clone(function(obj) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
      canvas[i].insertAt(obj, index, true);
    }
  });
};

$('#update').click(function() {
  updateCanvas();
});

function updateCanvas() {
  var json = JSON.stringify(canvas[0]);
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    canvas[i].loadFromJSON(json);
  }
}
// Toggling Images
function replaceImage(imgUrl) {
  if (!isImageLoaded) return; //return if initial image not loaded
  image.setSrc(imgUrl, function() {
    canvas[0].renderAll();
    updateCanvas();
  });
}

// Default (Blank)
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/SamdNdX.png', function(img) {
  isImageLoaded = true;
  image = img.set({
    selectable: false,
    evented: false,
  }).scale(0.5);
  canvas[0].add(image);
  canvas[0].sendToBack(image);
  updateCanvas();
});

$('#save').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#imagesave'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
      a.download = 'myfile.jpg';
      a.click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}

td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#imagesave {
  background-color: white;
  height: 637.5px;
  width: 825px;
  padding-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>

<button onclick="dropText();" class="dropdown-item">Add Text</button><button id="save">Save</button>
<button onclick="replaceImage('https://i.imgur.com/SamdNdX.png')">Blank</button>
<button onclick="replaceImage('https://i.imgur.com/RuZ5HTH.png')">Image A Pic</button>
<button onclick="replaceImage('https://i.imgur.com/u3Knj4R.png')">Image B Pic</button>

<div id="imagesave">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="c0" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc1" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc2" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc3" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc4" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc5" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc6" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc7" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```